# Deploying webapp with precompiled views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webdeploy

I want to deploy web application to the test server using web deploy method. Application builds normally without problems and works fine locally and on test server. Problem comes when I want to use precompiled settings during deploying. In the middle of this process i got a ton of errors in `VerifyCode.cshtml` file. Thing is I even don't have view called `VerifyCode` in my views folder. Where is the problem? I'm using anonymous and windows authentication in parallel.

My publish settings:
[image]
[image]

Example errors I receiveing:

```
The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context
The name 'Scripts' does not exist in the current context
The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context
'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'TextBoxFor' ...
```

And so on ...

`VerifyCode.cshtml` code:

```
@model App.Models.VerifyCodeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Verify";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("VerifyCode", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Hidden("provider", @Model.Provider)
    @Html.Hidden("rememberMe", @Model.RememberMe)
    <h4>Enter verification code</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Code, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberBrowser)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberBrowser)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to make it work. The problem was trivial. I have no idea how but I had view called `VerifyCode` in random place in my project.

The interesting fact is that VS searching text tools couldn't find it. I made a little research e.g. [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/102147/3-bugs-search-doesnt-find-anything-it-doesnt-searc.html) and found that there are some problems with text searching in VS and it's not always works as expected.

So while views were precompiled all view files was scraped together with this sneaky one without references.